# Correct model relationships, primary and foreign keys for cakephp2 queries

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have Franchisees that rent equipment
I have Customers that rent off Franchisees
Both Franchisees and Customers are Users

I have a User table, a Franchisee table, a Customer table, and a Booking table.

The tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `franchisees` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `franchisee_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `booking_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `event_location` text,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

My model relations are defined like this:

FRANCHISEE

```
public $name = 'Franchisee';
public $hasMany = array(
    'FranchiseeBooking' => array(
        'className'    => 'Booking',
        'foreignKey'   => 'franchisee_id'
    )
);
```

CUSTOMER

```
public $name = 'Customer';
public $hasMany = array(
    'CustomerBooking' => array(
        'className'  => 'Booking',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
    )
);
```

BOOKING

```
public $name = 'Booking';
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Customers' => array(
        'className'    => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey'   => 'customer_id'
    ),
    'Franchisees' => array(
        'className'    => 'Franchisee',
        'foreignKey'   => 'franchisee_id'
    )
);
```

So, I'm trying to query the Booking table (where franchisee_id is the logged in user) and get all bookings for the franchisee, as well as the related Customer data.

```
$options = array('conditions' =>  array('Booking.franchisee_id' => $this->_authUser));
$bookings = $this->Booking->find('all');
```

Results in the following query:

```
SELECT `Booking`.`id`, `Booking`.`customer_id`, `Booking`.`franchisee_id`, `Booking`.`booking_date`, `Booking`.`start_date`, `Booking`.`end_date`, `Booking`.`event_location`, `Booking`.`price`, `BookingCustomers`.`id`, `BookingCustomers`.`user_id`, `BookingCustomers`.`group_id`, `BookingCustomers`.`firstname`, `BookingCustomers`.`lastname`, `BookingCustomers`.`address1`, `BookingCustomers`.`address2`, `BookingCustomers`.`city`, `BookingCustomers`.`postcode`, `BookingCustomers`.`phone`, `BookingCustomers`.`alt_phone`, `BookingCustomers`.`lat`, `BookingCustomers`.`lng`, `BookingCustomers`.`created`, `BookingCustomers`.`modified`, `BookingFranchisees`.`id`, `BookingFranchisees`.`user_id`, `BookingFranchisees`.`group_id`, `BookingFranchisees`.`firstname`, `BookingFranchisees`.`lastname`, `BookingFranchisees`.`address1`, `BookingFranchisees`.`address2`, `BookingFranchisees`.`city`, `BookingFranchisees`.`postcode`, `BookingFranchisees`.`phone`, `BookingFranchisees`.`alt_phone`, `BookingFranchisees`.`lat`, `BookingFranchisees`.`lng`, `BookingFranchisees`.`created`, `BookingFranchisees`.`modified` FROM `trailblazer`.`bookings` AS `Booking` LEFT JOIN `trailblazer`.`customers` AS `BookingCustomers` ON (`Booking`.`customer_id` = `BookingCustomers`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `trailblazer`.`franchisees` AS `BookingFranchisees` ON (`Booking`.`franchisee_id` = `BookingFranchisees`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1
```

Which looks like this when the array is printed out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Booking] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [customer_id] => 8
                    [franchisee_id] => 7
                    [booking_date] => 2013-02-25 11:44:29
                    [start_date] => 2013-03-06 11:45:00
                    [end_date] => 2013-03-08 11:45:00
                    [event_location] => Belfast
                    [price] => 900
                )

            [BookingCustomers] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [user_id] => 
                    [group_id] => 
                    [firstname] => 
                    [lastname] => 
                    [address1] => 
                    [address2] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [phone] => 
                    [alt_phone] => 
                    [lat] => 
                    [lng] => 
                    [created] => 
                    [modified] => 
                )

            [BookingFranchisees] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [user_id] => 
                    [group_id] => 
                    [firstname] => 
                    [lastname] => 
                    [address1] => 
                    [address2] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [phone] => 
                    [alt_phone] => 
                    [lat] => 
                    [lng] => 
                    [created] => 
                    [modified] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Booking] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [customer_id] => 14
                    [franchisee_id] => 7
                    [booking_date] => 2013-02-25 16:18:44
                    [start_date] => 2013-02-08 16:15:00
                    [end_date] => 2013-02-23 16:15:00
                    [event_location] => 
                    [price] => 6750
                )

            [BookingCustomers] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [user_id] => 
                    [group_id] => 
                    [firstname] => 
                    [lastname] => 
                    [address1] => 
                    [address2] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [phone] => 
                    [alt_phone] => 
                    [lat] => 
                    [lng] => 
                    [created] => 
                    [modified] => 
                )

            [BookingFranchisees] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [user_id] => 
                    [group_id] => 
                    [firstname] => 
                    [lastname] => 
                    [address1] => 
                    [address2] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [phone] => 
                    [alt_phone] => 
                    [lat] => 
                    [lng] => 
                    [created] => 
                    [modified] => 
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, I'm not getting related data. I have a feeling the problem is related to primary keys vs. foreign keys, but I don't know where I'm going wrong. Can anyone figure this out? (I'm using cakephp 2.3)

Comment: Make sure you set `$recursive = -1;`, then post the new query it generates.  Also, why are you using an alias as opposed to just "Booking" for your hasMany associations?

Comment: are there any data inserted to the corresponding tables? It seems to me your relations are fine, since your `find()` method fetches all data as wanted. The problem is that your tables probably don't have any data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your User-Id is not called correctly. Try:

```
$options = array('conditions' =>  array('Booking.franchisee_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
```